# Deploy meteor, meteor-up and/or demeteorizer?

Tags: deployment, meteor, meteor-up, demeteorizer

I'm checking out my options on deploying meteor apps.

I already saw the problems of deploying meteor apps built on my mac, to remote Ubuntu server and other versioning issues, i believe more to come.

[meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) looks like a good solution, but can it be used alongside with [demeteorizer](https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer)
to handle dependency management?

Would that have any advantage over packaging with demeteorizing, and deploying with some othe/custom script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use demeteorizer, if you're using mup. You can configure npm binary dependencies in the config.

Personally I use mup in production, for over 10 different apps, and it even handles multi-node deploys nicely.

I recommend using something like chef to setup your environments, and then mup for meteor/node/mongo/phantom.